# ntpq utility on Alpine 3.9?

Tags: alpine-linux, ntp, telegraf

I want to use Telegraf's [ntpq's input](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/ntpq), to detect timedrift on some remote machines I run. This input requires access to the [ntpq binary](http://doc.ntp.org/4.1.0/ntpq.htm), which is part of the ntp package. However, my telegraf container is based on Alpine 3.9, and I simply cant find any way to install ntp on Alpine.

One thing I did find was this: [ntpsec](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86/ntpsec) is a competing project to ntp and has its own implementation of ntpq. This might actually work, but this package is only supported on the current Edge of Alpine (ie, not in Alpine <= 3.10), so that's no good.

Any helpful ideas on how to get ntpq on Alpine 3.9 (except for migrating my telegarf away from Alpine)?

Answer (score 1):

`ntpsec` is available since Alpine 3.10 using the community-repository:
https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=ntpq&path=&name=&branch=v3.10

So you can either upgrade your container to Alpine 3.10 or try to backport (and build) ntpsec on alpine 3.9

Comment: thank you! you're correct: 3.10 does support ntpsec. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve my problem as the ntpq plugin does not work. Perhaps this is because of some differences between ntp's ntpq and ntpsec's ntpq. I might just go with ubuntu after all.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by compiling the ntp package in a separate docker build stage and copying out the ntpq executable like this:

```
FROM alpine:3.17 AS ntp_builder
RUN apk add alpine-sdk linux-headers
RUN wget -q http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~ntp/ntp_spool/ntp4/ntp-4.2/ntp-4.2.8p15.tar.gz
RUN tar xf ntp-4.2.8p15.tar.gz
RUN cd ntp-4.2.8p15 && ./configure && make

FROM alpine:3.17
RUN echo 'hosts: files dns' >> /etc/nsswitch.conf
RUN apk add --no-cache iputils ca-certificates net-snmp-tools \
    procps lm_sensors \
    && update-ca-certificates
COPY --from=ntp_builder /ntp-4.2.8p15/ntpq /usr/bin
COPY telegraf /usr/bin/
COPY telegraf.conf /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf

EXPOSE 8125/udp 8092/udp 8094

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["telegraf"]
```

Note, you need allow the docker container to query the ntp daemon by adding a line like `restrict 172.18.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0` to ntp.conf on the host.